# HTML/CSS: "See Through Background" Text?

Tags: html, css

Ok, is this possible.

I have a background image.  On top of that, I have a transparent grey box for content.  I'd like to have title at the top in text, that is basically the letters *exposing* the background.  So, the text removes the grey box and lets the background show through.

The only hacky way I can see is create an image with the letters transparent on a background the same grey color, and then try to somehow align that with the grey box.

Is there another - better - way?

Comment: It may help to use CSS 3 opacity property. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Why is that "hacky"? It's a layer with a transparency.

Comment: The only way I can think of is WebKit-only. Is that okay?

Comment: @Celeritas - Consider avoiding linking to w3schools here at Stackoverflow; it's a "strained" relationship, let's say. Link to the specifications, to sites like HTMLDog, Sitepoint... Just not w3schools (see http://w3fools.com). FYI

Comment: @minitech - I'd sure like more information on what you're thinking about.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: `-webkit-background-clip: text` with multiple backgrounds. Maybe. I'm still working it out :P (Although, if the background is static, then it will be very simple.)

Comment: @minitech - Ah, very cool. [Demo here](http://trentwalton.com/bgclip/), plus webkit's [blog entry on the subject](http://www.webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I say hacky because it requires me lining up the image with the grey content div.  Ick.

Comment: Is the background static? Or could it move if, for example, you resize the browser window? Do you have an image showing the effect?

Comment: @JaredFarrish acknowledged, consider http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/ instead

Comment: @thirtydot: It can move around relative to the grey content box.

Comment: So the text is a cutout only for removing the gray containing box to show the underlying background image, but otherwise will not affect anything else? Like an alpha channel?

Comment: Would you be interested in a JavaScript solution to support more browsers? Or would you be happy with a WebKit-only pure CSS solution?

Comment: @thirtydot - Either way, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @thirtydot - I'm with Jared Farrish, I'd like to see it even if it involves JS.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yeah, like a inverse mask I suppose?

Comment: What I was imagining is what jasssonpet's fiddle looks like in Chrome. Is that what you were after?

Comment: You can also create a reversed font face (where each glyph is cut out of a solid block instead of the glyph itself being the solid area), and use @font-face.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way is to use `-webkit-background-clip: text;`: **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NT7z7/11/)** (webkit only obviously).

Using position, we can sync both backgrounds:

```
#container, #container h1 {
    background: url(bg.png)
}

#container {
    position: relative;
}

#container #gray {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    padding-top: 8em;
}

#container h1 {
    font-size: 8em;
    padding-top: /* padding + border of div */;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}​
```

Or you could use the same approach and apply a [svg mask](http://jsfiddle.net/NT7z7/12/), that will work in all modern browsers.

Comment: That's actually pretty nifty in Chrome.

Comment: That looks perfect in Webkit - can you elaborate on how to use the CVG for non-webkit?

Comment: @mtyson http://jsfiddle.net/NT7z7/12/ You should use some js to generate the SVG, to keep the source clean.

Comment: background-clip: text is also available in FF49. -webkit-text-fill-color is also apparently supported in FF49, if  layout.css.prefixes.webkit are set to true, which are set by default since version 49. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color